# Symfony2 translation in twig using CsvFileLoader

Tags: php, symfony, twig, language-translation

I want to implement translation in Symfony2 using csvFileLoader. In config.yml translation field is enabled and locale set to fr.
I have written following code in controller.

```
    $file = //file path eg: messages.fr.csv;
    $loader = new CsvFileLoader($file);
    $loader->setCsvControl(',');
    $x = $loader->load($file, 'fr');
    $translator = new Translator('fr',new MessageSelector());
    $translator->addLoader('csv', $loader);
    $translator->addResource('csv', $file, 'fr','messages');
    $translator->trans('Symfony is great');
```

Above code works fine. If I use trans tag in twig then text is not translated. Even I add twig extentions:-

```
    $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem("path to twig template file");
    $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
    $twig->addExtension(new TranslationExtension($translator));
```

And Code in witten in twig file

```
    {% trans %}Symfony2 is great{% endtrans %}
```

Above text is not translated in twig. I tried it using .xlf file then it works but for .csv file translation is not working.
Need solution for above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 0):

Controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("{_locale}/translate1")
 */
public function showTwoAction(Request $request) 
{
    $delimiter = ";";
    $enclosure = '"';
    $escape = '\\';
    $file = __DIR__.'/file_'.$request->getLocale().'.csv';      


    $translator = new Translator($request->getLocale(), new MessageSelector());
    $translator->addLoader('csv', new CsvFileLoader());
    $translator->addResource('csv', $file, $request->getLocale());
    $catalogue = $translator->getCatalogue($request->getLocale());
    $messages = $catalogue->all();

    while ($catalogue = $catalogue->getFallbackCatalogue()) 
    {
        $messages = array_replace_recursive($catalogue->all(), $messages);
    }

    return $this->render("PRIYACoreTranslateBundle:Default:translate.html.twig",$messages);
}
```

Twig :

```
{{ messages.Hi }}
{{ messages.Hello }}
```

Translation CSV Files

=> **file_en.csv**

```
"Hi";"Hi"
"Hello";"Hello"
```

=> **file_fr.csv**

```
"Hi";"salut"
"Hello";"Bonjour"
```

Hope it helps.